# Select the day from a date as a result of the select operation

Tags: sql, date, select, sqlite

Here is my query:

```
SELECT DAY(Fecha) FROM tAsistencia WHERE Alumno = 2;
```

The query is intended to simply return the day part of the date (Fecha is DATE type column) However I get the error that DAY is an unknown function. How do I get the intended result?

Comment: Please supply the schema and what format Fecha is in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite doesn't have a `day` function. You could use `strftime` to get that functionality, though:

```
SELECT STRFTIME('%d', Fecha) FROM tAsistencia WHERE Alumno = 2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use **strftime** function like that:

```
SELECT STRFTIME('%d', Fecha) FROM tAsistencia WHERE Alumno = 2;
```